# Finding a Match using java.lang.String.matches()

Tags: java, regex

I have a String that contains new line characters say...

`str = "Hello\n"+"Batman,\n" + "Joker\n" + "here\n"`

I would want to know how to find the existance of a particular word say .. `Joker` in the string  `str` using `java.lang.String.matches()`

I find that `str.matches(".*Joker.*")` returns `false` and returns `true` if i remove the new line characters. So what would be the regex expression to be used as an argument to `str.matches()`?

One way is... `str.replaceAll("\\n","").matches(.*Joker.*);`

Comment: Note that you will get true for `"asdfJokerasdf"` - is it what you really want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the dot in `.*` does not match newlines by default. If you want newlines to be matched, your regex must have the flag [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL).

If you want to embed that in a regex used in `.matches()` the regex would be:

```
"(?s).*Joker.*"
```

However, note that this will match `Jokers` too. A regex does not have the notion of words. Your regex would therefore *really* need to be:

```
"(?s).*\\bJoker\\b.*"
```

However, a regex does not need to match *all* its input text (which is what `.matches()` does, counterintuitively), only what is needed. Therefore, this solution is even better, and does not require `Pattern.DOTALL`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bJoker\\b"); // \b is the word anchor

p.matcher(str).find(); // returns true
```

Comment: any reason why i cannot do this way `str.matches("\\bJoker\\b");` ?

Comment: It is because `.matches()` is misnamed: it tries and matches the whole input against the regex; in effect, it surrounds all the regex with `^` and `$`. Hence my solution using a `Pattern`: `.find()` does real regex matching.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something much simpler; this is a `contains`. You do not need the power of regex:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String str = "Hello\n" + "Batman,\n" + "Joker\n" + "here\n";
    System.out.println(str.contains("Joker"));
}
```

Alternatively you can use a `Pattern` and `find`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String str = "Hello\n" + "Batman,\n" + "Joker\n" + "here\n";
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Joker");
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found match");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a Pattern that uses the DOTALL flag, which says that a dot should also match new lines.

```
String str = "Hello\n"+"Batman,\n" + "Joker\n" + "here\n";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("".*Joker.*", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(str);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // found a match
} 
else
{
  // no match
}
```